# Convergence of a product sequence in a metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces with $X=\mathbb{R}^N, Y=\mathbb{R}$. Then $xy\in X$ for every $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Also let $(x_n)\to x$ in $X$ and $y_n\to y$ in $Y$. What is the minimal condition needed so that $(x_ny_n)\to xy$ in $X$? Without further conditions $(x_ny_n)\not\to xy$ in $X$. For example, consider $X=\mathbb{R}=Y$ and $d_X$ be the discrete metric and $d_Y$ be the euclidean metric. Take $x_n=1,y_n=\frac{1}{n}, \forall n$. Then $x_n\to 1$ in $(X,d_X)$, $y_n\to 0$ in $(Y,d_Y)$, but $x_ny_n=\frac{1}{n}\not\to 0$ in $(X,d_X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criterion that you want is just the continuity of the product $\pi : X\times Y \rightarrow X$. If product is continuous, then by one of the equivalent definitions, 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \pi(x_n,y_n)= \pi\big(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (x_n,y_n)\big) = \pi\big(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  x_n,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  y_n\big)$$
that is 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (x_n\cdot y_n) = (\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n)\cdot(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} y_n) $$
If it's not then it means that there will exist sequences for which this relation is not satisfied.

You can also use any other applicable definiton of continuity (for example the one using the notion of open sets, or the one using the notion of the graph of a function) to check the continuity of a product.

It can also be proven that for $X$ and $Y$ being metric spaces, the product $\pi:X\times Y\rightarrow X$ is continuous iff

1. for every $x\in X$ function $f_x: Y \ni y \mapsto xy \in X$ is continuous, and
2. for every $y\in Y$ function $g_y: X \ni  x \mapsto xy \in X$ is continuous.